# One <td> same width as two <td>'s

Tags: html, css, dom

I have a table

```
<table>
       <tr>
           <td class="tableheading">Heading 1</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>Text 1</td>
           <td>Text 2</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td class="tableheading">Heading 2</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>Text 3</td>
           <td>Text 4</td>
       </tr>
</table>
```

and I want the

```
<td class="tableheading">
```

to fill up the same space as the two td's below.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: Are you looking for `colspan`? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use colspan="2"

```
<td class="tableheading" colspan="2">
```